# CentOS RPM Packages

Tags: centos, rpm

When I do `rpm -qa | grep nano` I can see that Nano Text Editor is installed onto my CentOS box.

But when I do `rpm -qpi nano-2.9.8-1.el8.x86_64.rpm` in the below given directory it shows me **Install Date: (not installed)**

**Directory:** cd /run/media/root/CentOS-8-BaseOS-x86_64/BaseOS/Packages/

```
[root@karancentos ~]# cd /run/media/root/CentOS-8-BaseOS-x86_64/BaseOS/Packages/
[root@karancentos Packages]# rpm -qpi nano-2.9.8-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
Name        : nano
Version     : 2.9.8
Release     : 1.el8
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: (not installed)
Group       : Unspecified
Size        : 2328511
License     : GPLv3+
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Mon 01 Jul 2019 08:15:52 PM EDT, Key ID 05b555b38483c65d
Source RPM  : nano-2.9.8-1.el8.src.rpm
Build Date  : Sat 11 May 2019 11:03:56 AM EDT
Build Host  : x86-02.mbox.centos.org
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : CentOS Buildsys <bugs@centos.org>
Vendor      : CentOS
URL         : https://www.nano-editor.org
Summary     : A small text editor
Description :
GNU nano is a small and friendly text editor.
```

I'm not sure why does it comes up when doing `rpm -qa | grep nano` and then when I do `rpm -qpi nano-2.9.8-1.el8.x86_64.rpm` it shows me **Install Date: (not installed)**

Can someone please help me understand this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `rpm -qpi <file>` you're only querying a specific RPM package on the filesystem, here `nano-2.9.8-1.el8.x86_64.rpm`. However, without querying the RPM database (which does not happen if you use `-p` parameter!), the package is shown as "not installed". Only the RPM database knows if a package is installed or not. You're looking for `rpm -qi <package>`, thus `rpm -qi nano` in the specific case – this queries the RPM database and you will get the install date.